# SCSS optimization

Tags: css, class, sass

Below is my `scss` code, it gives expected output. But I feel it looks dirty that the `-nrb` repeats in both `__red` and `__green`, is there a way to simplify this?

```
$cell-header: '.cell-header';
#{$cell-header} {
    &__red {
        @extend .ui-grid-column-menu-button;
        color: $red-cell-color;
        background-color: $red-cell-bgcolor;
        border: solid 1px $red-cell-color;

        // no right border
        &-nrb{
            @extend .cell-header__red;
            border-right: none;
        }
    }

    &__green {
        @extend .ui-grid-column-menu-button;
        color: $green-cell-color;
        background-color: $green-cell-bgcolor;
        border: solid 1px $green-cell-color;

        // no right border
        &-nrb{
            @extend .cell-header__green;
            border-right: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, what is the correct way of extending the underlying class? Right now I have hard-coded the class name in `@extend` in `-nrb`, some keywords like `this`

Answer (score 0):

You can group `red` and `green`:

```
$cell-header: '.cell-header';
#{$cell-header} {
    &__red {
        color: $red-cell-color;
        background-color: $red-cell-bgcolor;
        border: solid 1px $red-cell-color;
    }

    &__green {
        color: $green-cell-color;
        background-color: $green-cell-bgcolor;
        border: solid 1px $green-cell-color;
    }

    &__red, &__green{
        @extend .ui-grid-column-menu-button;

        // no right border
        &-nrb{
            @extend .cell-header__green;
            border-right: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as per the answer `-nrb` extends `.cell-header__green` always.. but i need `.cell-header__red-nrb` extend `cell-header__red` , and similarly `.cell-header__green-nrb` extend `cell-header__green`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do some thing like this
    $cell-header: '.cell-header';
    @mixin headermixin ($cell-color, $cell-bgcolor) {
        @extend .ui-grid-column-menu-button;
         color: $cell-color;
         background-color: $cell-bgcolor;
         border: solid 1px $cell-color;

```
}

#{$cell-header} {
    &__red {
        @include headermixin($red-cell-color,$red-cell-bgcolor,.cell-header__red)
    &-nrb{
          @extend .cell-header__red;
            border-right: none;
    }


    }

    &__green {
         @include headermixin($green-cell-color,$green-cell-bgcolor,.cell-header__green)
     &-nrb{
         @extend $cell-header__green
            border-right: none;
    }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Thanks